# Rails activerecord deep eager loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Here is my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  has_many :comments
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
end
```

I need to get ***comment*** records from current ***user*** ***products*** only

How do I do that? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we move the relationships to use a `has_many: comments, through: products` you can probably get what you're after:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  has_many :comments, through: products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Now you can do `user.comments`.

The rails docs are [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association), which say:

> A has_many :through association is often used to set up a many-to-many
>   connection with another model. This association indicates that the
>   declaring model can be matched with zero or more instances of another
>   model by proceeding through a third model. For example, consider a
>   medical practice where patients make appointments to see physicians.